# Doubt on differential

Tags: differential-geometry

I've got a doubt on a definition on my notes:
"The differential is the operator $d: C^\infty(U)\rightarrow \Omega^1(U)$ defind by the formula $df(v)=v(f) \quad (1)$".

Here $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $v$ is a smooth vector field on $U$. But there is something I don't understand because, since
$d: C^\infty(U)\rightarrow \Omega^1(U)$, then $df\in \Omega^1(U)$, so $df:U\rightarrow T^\star U$, then I should apply $df$ to something which stays in $U$. But a vector field doesn't stay in $U$.

Also in the rhs of $(1)$ there's something not clear to me: if $v$ is a vector field, then it has sense $[v(p)](f)$, where $p\in U$, because $v(p)\in T_p\mathbb{R}^n$ and so I can apply it to $f$; but for me that's something wrong in "$v(f)$", since $v$ is a vector field and so $v:U\rightarrow TU$.

P.S. $T^\star U$ is the cotangent bundle and $TU$ is the tangent bundle of U.

Comment: What do you mean by "vector field doesn't stay in $U$"? Where does it go? I am also not clear about your confusion in the last paragraph. You know how to apply $v$ pointwise, so what's the problem with applying it globally? Same way $v(p)$ corresponds to derivation at $p$, $v$ globally corresponds to a derivation $X \in Der(U)$ in the algebra of derivations on $U$ that take smooth functions to smooth functions and obey Leibniz's rule.

Comment: I mean that $v$ is a map from $U$ to $TU$, and it is not an element of $U$. For me the correct formula is $[df(p)]v(p)=[v(p)](f)$, $p\in U$.

Comment: I think your confusion is only notational. The expression $df(v)$ defines a function on $U$ by $[df(v)](p) =[df(p)]v(p)$. All of these objects (vector fields, form fields, functions) are local, so by applying one object to the other what we really mean is that we do it at every point $p \in U$.

Comment: Ok, thank you Marek, I think, as you said, I was in confusion on the notation!

Comment: Glad to hear that, you're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Marek said in comments: although we think of vector fields as "smooth" selections of a tangent vector at every point, they are often defined *not* as a map   from $U$ to $TU$, but rather as a map from $C^\infty(U)$ to $C^\infty(U)$ (with the properties of being linear and satisfying the Leibniz rule). With this approach, $v(f)$ makes perfect sense from the beginning. A vector field takes a smooth function and produces another smooth function. A differential of   $f$   takes  a vector field and produces a function: namely, the result of applying the field to $f$.